# Application request on Apache Access Log

Tags: apache, web-services, logging, glassfish-4

I´m creating a Web Service using Glassfish. Now I want to know basic information about my requests like:

[DATE] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200

For that I installed apache 2.2. It has 3 logs: access.log, error.log and install.log. How can I known basic information of my application using access.log?In other words, How can I direct my application requests to access log?

Comment: is apache configured as reverse proxy ? and what kind of application related information are you trying to check ?

Comment: Basically I want to know session id, date and type of request (200, 404) and if possible the time for each request. I configured apache server as default using hostname an port 80. I don t know nothing more about apache

Answer (score 0):

If you need session id, date, HTTP status code and other important log information update below directive in your apache configuration file.

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{Set-Cookie}o\"" more_logs
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log more_logs
```

Here `"%{Set-Cookie}o\"` will enable logging of sessions.

If you still need more log information refer [this documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats).

Comment: But this will allow me to have my applications requests on access log? My access log is not catching anything at this time.

Comment: Yes the above configuration should work. Check if u have updated them correctly and see if any duplicate configuration exists and remove it. Dont forget that these settings have to be added to apace's  main configuration file.